# Eclipse PHP xdebug stuck at 78% (with MAMP)

Tags: php, eclipse, macos, xdebug

This is on my mac: `Eclipse IDE`. I can't seem to get `xdebug` to complete when I issue the debug order.

It get stuck at 78% saying

> "Launching : waiting for XDebug session ..."

I've tried to modify the php.ini file to no avail ...

Here is my config :

```
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/lib/php/extensions/no-    
debug-non-zts-20151012/xdebug.so"
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "/tmp/xdebug/"
xdebug.profiler_enable = true
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
```

Answer (score 1):

You need set debug session in url for example `XDEBUG_SESSION_START=your_key`. You can config this session key in your idea. End you need configuration your idea 'eclipse' for remote debug.